# How to configure Apache web server to redirect the requests it receives without modifying the source IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, ip, apache-2.4

Unfortunately I don't know about web servers but I'm trying to help a colleague. We have an Apache web server setup and we need it to <strike>redirect</strike> resend the requests it gets to an application server while keeping the source ip the same it was when apache received it.

Whats happening is:

1. A client (IP: 1.1.1.1) sends a request to Apache web server
2. Apache web server (IP: **2.2.2.2**) redirects its requests to an application server
3. The application server sees the source IP as (**2.2.2.2**) which is Apache's !

How can I configure Apache to let it redirect the requests to the Application server without changing the source IP, so in the mentioned example, the application server would receive 1.1.1.1 as the source IP address.

Sadly, using headers is our last option because it will force us to do a wide scale change in our applications.

Comment: I have no idea whether that feature exists in Apache. Regardless of whether you are using Apache or something else, it is going to require some nasty hacks in your networking setup to make it work. I would strongly recommend against it. Instead I recommend using the `X-Forwarded-For` header which exists for this purpose. Going over all the places where you are depending on client IP addresses is likely going to be useful anyway since your question give me the impression you are lacking IPv6 support in all the same places.

Comment: The term `redirect` in the question is confused - you aren't describing any redirects.

Comment: The question is why do you need this? It sounds strange and maybe you'd just need to use mod_remoteip/mod_rpaf/mod_cloudflare instead.

Comment: @AD7six, I mean that Apache has to receive the requests and resend it again to the application server.

Comment: @faker, I need to do this because the applications running on the application server need to know the IP of the client from which the request originated. So Apache's IP should be irrelevant.

Comment: I knew what you meant, the terminology is simply wrong when speaking about a web server. "apache's IP" is who your application server will respond to - were you to change that apache wouldn't receive any response from sent requests. [a reference](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/can-i-trust-the-source-ip-of-an-http-request).

Comment: If I remember correctly, Apache sends a header (X_FORWARDED_FOR) that has the original client's IP. Can the application read this?

Comment: Using the header _is_ the way to do this, and your application should already be aware of and capable to read the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: Right, dashes instead of underscores. Been doing too much programming recently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the IP address so you don't have to do the wide scale application change you mentioned, you can enable IP forwarding and then do forwarding of the traffic at the IP level rather than via proxying (see http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/ for an example).

If using Windows, check out `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4` (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1).

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Thanks for the clarification - I've added a possible Windows solution to my answer

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I hope you were able to get your issue resolved.  If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted and/or upvote it so I can get credit for it.  Thanks

Answer (score -4):

You should use a reverse proxy and not a webserver to do so, try to install nginx (which does both reverse proxy and webserver).

It will allow you to do exactly what you want, by, basicly instead of configuring a filesystem path, you will configure a network path (Your application server).

Comment: Apache with mod_proxy could handle this just as well. And your answer does not include how to keep the original client IP preserved.